# adding cors support to all the routes in hapijs 17.2

Tags: cors, hapi.js

Looking at the docs for the latest 17.2.0 release, it seems to me that I have to add cors support to each route explicitly. However, the following does not work for me

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: path,
    handler: handler,
    options: {
        cors: true
    }
});
```

And, even if it did, would really like to add cors support to all the routes in one place instead of doing it for every route separately. In the previous versions, I could do the following

```
server.connection({ routes: { cors: true } });
```

But that doesn't seem to be possible anymore. What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In hapijs 17, you initialize the connection details with the servers constructor. server.connection() is no longer available.

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({  
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000,
  routes: {cors: true}
})
```

[Source: hapijs API](https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionscors)